# Should I use const in this function argument?

Tags: c

I'm working on getting myself comfortable with C after only working in high level languages for the past 10 years.  I've done rust as well and really like the concept of notating immutability in functions.

That being said I'm confused on if I should use `const` wherever the compiler lets me, or just use it where it semantically makes sense (and hope no one comes behind me and does something the caller doesn't expect).

Several functions I am looking at right now are:

```
void kcr_scene_update(const struct KCR_Scene* scene) {
    scene->internal->cubeRotation.x += 0.01f;
    scene->internal->cubeRotation.y += 0.01f;
    scene->internal->cubeRotation.z += 0.01f;
}

void kcr_display_begin_frame(const struct KCR_Display* display) {
    for (int x = 0; x < display->windowWidth * display->windowHeight; x++) {
        display->pixelBuffer[x] = 0xFF000000;
    }
}
```

The compiler is allowing these, presumably because it's not changing the root pointer or direct child pointers (I guess?) but is it good practice to put const in these methods when I know there's some mutation going on?

Comment: What compiler are you using, with what flags? I'd be surprised if `-Wall` doesn't complain about this.

Comment: Anyway, this question is somewhat too narrow, with your `kcr` methods divorced from the rest of your code. Please show more of your code, so that we can give a more general code review.

Comment: @reinderien: I'm using GCC with -Wall and -Wextra, and it doesn't complain (to my surprise).  I'm not totally sure what extra code would be relevant.  If this isn't the right SE for this question then fine, but the question only revolved around code reviewing const in this circumstance.

Comment: I was able to confirm your issue locally. The crux of the problem is that `const` _does_ apply to `struct` sub-instances but does _not_ apply to `struct` sub-pointers. You should put together a minimum verifiable complete compilable example, including a simple struct definition, to illustrate this - and then just post it in StackOverflow.

Comment: Will do thanks.  I kept going back and forth if this would be too subjective for Stack overflow, but will do :)

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: We require that the poster know why the code is written the way it is. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Personally I think this question would be just fine on SO, but that's just me. If you get it closed both here and on SO, then maybe ask on software.codidact.com instead. It's a site much more tolerant to program design and style questions. It also allows code review questions, so you don't need to worry about which site to pick.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use const in this function argument?

Yes.

1. Better conveys to a user code's functionality. Consider the user may only see the declaration `void kcr_scene_update(const struct KCR_Scene* scene);` (in some header file) and not the definition.
2. Allows increased applicability.  Function can be *called* with  `const struct KCR_Scene* some_pointer`.  Without a `const` in the function signature, the caller is obliged to pass a non-const pointer.
3. Optimization: Some optimization will only take place when the reference data is `const`.  This issue applies especially to older compilers.

> good practice to put const in these methods when I know there's some mutation going on?

Need to see detail of `struct KCR_Scene` and `struct KCR_Display` to know what changes are really occurring in code.

---

I now see OP really needs to provide more info  - making answer wiki.